# How to best organize Underscore.js templates for use with Backbone.js?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, underscore.js, pug

Currently I have my main.jade file which is served using Express.js on Node.js. In the head of the jade file, I have all of my templates. As you can probably understand, this got unruly very quickly. I load the templates from Backbone.js using:

```
template:_.template($("#phone-tmplt-taskRow").html())
```

My app will have three versions: mobile, tablet, and desktop. I was wondering what the best way to organize my templates should be. I do not want to have ~30 templates listed in the head of my html file. How should I organize my templates? I would prefer to have 3 files somehow, one for each version. I do not want to serve a different URL from node.js/express.js depending on the version.

Comment: There is no specific way to do this. But i just did this Tried putting all the templates in the page as `<script type="text/template">` this gives me best readability and place i can look for the templates. a C# parser that strips all the `<script type="text/template">` then mush them to Hash in javascript

Comment: That is exactly what I don't want to do. I don't want 30 templates lined up in one giant HTML file.

Comment: If you know C# i may share the code with you. Otherwise you can use excellent Cassette library by Andrewway it does all these for you automatically

Comment: I know C#, I'd love to see what you're using.

Comment: you might want to also try this out 1st. It works really well with Hogan.js http://getcassette.net/. Since Hogan is used by Twitter themselves you might get a hint at that it is great :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually ended up using the ['include' feature of jade.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/#a13) to do what I needed. I have three .jade files for each version of my app and I include all of them in my main.jade. I am assuming I will ultimately result in using require.js for my project in the future, so thank you for your tips w/ that, eabait.

Answer (score 4):

you can separate templates in files (such as phone-tpl.html) and put all of them in a /templates directory. Then you can load each of them through AJAX, in that case I recommend you to have a cache (in memory or localStorage) to minimize request numbers.

Another options is using RequireJS. Addy Osmani have proposed the use of text! plugin to load templates. A more sophisticated option was proposed by Alex Sexton, where you dont load templates as text but precompiled as Javascript functions (and when optimized with r.js all templates get bundled, so in production all templates are functions and you dont request them to the server).

Links:

- http://alexsexton.com/talks/backboneconf2012/
- http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/
- RequireJS templating plugins: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Plugins#wiki-templating

Comment: Dust.js templates advocate pre-rendering to js functions, then these can all be stored in separate js files and pulled in with an AMD loader or via AJAX

Comment: exactly, the same as Handlebars.js or Hogan.js. There are many options out there ;). Check this: http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more

Comment: Yep, that's what got me into dust.js :) love it! Haven't tried many others tbh

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Jade templates for everything - server and client side.  No underscore templates.  I used http://projects.jga.me/clientjade/, which takes jade templates and precompiles them into a single js file.  Advantages:

1. No templates in your html files.  Smaller, more sane markup
2. Precompiled jade templates are blazing fast
3. Jade files can still be used to render html
4. Single template system

clientjade doesn't watch for file changes.  So I made a cake task that would handle that.  If you go that route, check out my cake task - https://gist.github.com/4041281

Answer (score 0):

You could put them into js files and load them with requirejs. That produces quite readable code and reduces dom dependence.